# R Leaflet: Add a Range Slider to Filter Markers without Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have a dataset like the one below. Is there a way without shiny (e.g. any javascript code or leaflet plugins) to add a range slider to filter the points based on the values in a column (e.g. a Date variable)? Something like in the code below with an expected output similar to the image below. Again, I need this functionality without the use of shiny.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   lat= c(50.9, 50.8, 50.5, 50.5, 51),
                   lon = c(-0.7, -0.92, -1, -0.8, -0.9),
                   date = c("2020-06-01", "2020-05-07", "2020-03-24", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-26"))

data %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
  addMarkers(lat=~lat, lng=~lon) %>%
  addRangeSlider(~date)
```

Expected Output Format:

[image]

Comment: You can use the `crosstalk` package.  Its first example on https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/ looks like what you want.

Comment: looks like you need this plugin... https://dwilhelm89.github.io/LeafletSlider/  you can try to make in work in R.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330 This is exactly what I need! I'm surprised I hadn't come across it sooner.

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel. I will see if this can be made to work with R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment of @user2554330, here is a `crosstalk`-solution.

````
---
title: "crossover test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library( crosstalk )
library( leaflet )
library( dplyr )
```

```{r load data }
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   lat= c(50.9, 50.8, 50.5, 50.5, 51),
                   lon = c(-0.7, -0.92, -1, -0.8, -0.9),
                   date = c("2020-06-01", "2020-05-07", "2020-03-24", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-26"))

data <- data %>% dplyr::mutate( date2 = as.numeric( as.Date( date ) ),
                                date3 = as.Date( date )
                                )
```

```{r maak shared data object}
shared_data <- SharedData$new( data )
```

```{r genereer output}
filter_slider("date", "Date", shared_data, ~date3, width = "100%")
leaflet(shared_data, width = "100%", height = 800) %>%
  leaflet::addTiles() %>%
  leaflet::addMarkers() 
```
````

[image]