# Incorporating Sliders into a Leaflet Map

Tags: html, r, leaflet, interactive

I was following this tutorial here (https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/) and tried to run the code:

```
library(crosstalk)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)

# Wrap data frame in SharedData
sd <- SharedData$new(quakes[sample(nrow(quakes), 100),])

# Create a filter input
filter_slider("mag", "Magnitude", sd, column=~mag, step=0.1, width=250)

# Use SharedData like a dataframe with Crosstalk-enabled widgets
map = bscols(
  leaflet(sd) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(),
  datatable(sd, extensions="Scroller", style="bootstrap", class="compact", width="100%",
    options=list(deferRender=TRUE, scrollY=300, scroller=TRUE))
)
```

The map seems to render, but the "interactive slider" does not appear:

[image]

Also, I can not seem to save this map:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(map, "map.html", selfcontained = F, libdir = "lib")

Error in .getNamespace(pkg) : 
  invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation
```

I heard that the slider might require installing some further add-ons, but I have not been able to find out how to do this.

- Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this problem?

Thank you!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.23         leaflet_2.1.1   crosstalk_1.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] jquerylib_0.1.4   pillar_1.7.0      compiler_4.1.3    bslib_0.3.1       tools_4.1.3       digest_0.6.29     lubridate_1.8.0  
 [8] jsonlite_1.8.0    lifecycle_1.0.1   tibble_3.1.6      pkgconfig_2.0.3   rlang_1.0.2       cli_3.3.0         DBI_1.1.2        
[15] yaml_2.3.5        xfun_0.30         fastmap_1.1.0     dplyr_1.0.9       stringr_1.4.0     generics_0.1.3    vctrs_0.4.1      
[22] htmlwidgets_1.5.4 sass_0.4.1        hms_1.1.1         tidyselect_1.1.2  glue_1.6.2        R6_2.5.1          fansi_1.0.3      
[29] purrr_0.3.4       tidyr_1.2.0       readr_2.1.2       tzdb_0.3.0        magrittr_2.0.2    ellipsis_0.3.2    htmltools_0.5.2  
[36] assertthat_0.2.1  utf8_1.2.2        tinytex_0.40      stringi_1.7.6     lazyeval_0.2.2    crayon_1.5.1
```

Comment: Hi, The code works as expected within Markdown. Are you expecting to see the slider above the map in your IDE viewer?

Comment: @ susan: thank you! I would like to save the output as an html file and still see the slider. did this work for you? thank you!

Comment: Yes, I was able to run in Markdown to html